# Disable forgot password for SSO Users

Tags: single-sign-on, identity

We have enabled SSO for our users. How can I prevent users from using salesforce login(login.salesforce.com) if they know saleforce password from before setting up sso or if they reset their password via forgot password link? 
I cannot use the My domain login policy setting to restrict users from logging in via login.salesforce.com as I want admins to still login via standard salesforce login. Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always have admins login using direct URL even when the `Prevent login from ...` is enabled. The way to do so is to append a query parameter `login` in the login URL (example below) where admins can still use their Salesforce username and password.

```
https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/?login
```

You can find more details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/domain_name_guidelines.htm).

It's advisable that you [expire passwords for all users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=expiring_passwords.htm&type=5) so that even if they can get access using the query parameter, they won't be able to login. But if for any reasons any User has access to this URL, and that they have their Salesforce password known to them, they can still login using their Salesforce username/password.

Comment: Thank you Jayant. Will the fall back url .../login work for actual users too if they know their salesforce password?

Comment: Yes. To avoid that situation, its best that you expire password for all users before restricting the login. I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Jayant, if users get to know the ?/login url they can reset the password via forgot password link and can login to sandbox with out going through SSO. anyway we can prevent that flow?

Comment: Make sure such Users have `Is Single Sign-On Enabled` permission set on their profile. In that case even if they can reach to the login page, but they won't be able to reset their password. I will recommend you take a look at the [doc here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_tips.htm&type=5)

Comment: But that permission is not available unless you have Delegated Authentication enabled and we don't have delegated authentication showing up in the single sign on page.

Comment: Read the docs -- *If the Is Single Sign-On Enabled permission isn’t available, ask Salesforce Support to enable the delegated authentication feature. You’re not required to configure delegated authentication, but it must be enabled.* There's no other way to restrict users who know this URL to be able to not use their password.